# Problem in implementing Quiescence Search

Tags: python, chess, minmax

I am trying to implement quiescence search along with negamax algorithm for my chess engine program .
What I have done till now :

This is the code for my Negamax function which I call in the main part of my code :

```
def findMoveNegaMaxAlphaBeta(gs, validMoves, depth, alpha, beta, turnMultiplier, nextMove):

if depth == 0 :
    requiredMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
    actual_score = quiescienceSearch(gs, requiredMoves, alpha, beta, 1 if gs.whiteToMove else -1)
    return actual_score

maxScore = -CHECKMATE
for move in validMoves :
    gs.makeMove(move)
    nextMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
    score = -findMoveNegaMaxAlphaBeta(gs, nextMoves, depth - 1 , -beta, -alpha, -turnMultiplier, nextMove)
    if score > maxScore:
        maxScore = score
        if depth == DEPTH :
            nextMove.put(move)
    gs.undoMove() 
    if maxScore > alpha:   # This is were pruning happens
        alpha = maxScore
    if alpha >= beta :
        break    

return maxScore
```

I read on https://www.chessprogramming.org/Quiescence_Search that  "At the beginning of quiescence, the position's evaluation is used to establish a lower bound on the score. This is theoretically sound because we can usually assume that there is at least one move that can either match or beat the lower bound."  I tried to implement it by setting the initial maximum score to the static Evaluation of the board before we calculate any further captures .

This is the code for my Quiescence Function :

```
def quiescienceSearch(gs, validMoves, alpha, beta, turnmultiplier):
quiescienceMoves = []
for move in validMoves:
    if "x" in move.getChessNotation():
        quiescienceMoves.append(move)
if len(quiescienceMoves) == 0:
    return turnmultiplier * scoreBoard(gs)     

maxScore =  scoreBoard(gs)
for move in quiescienceMoves :
    print(move.getChessNotation())
    gs.makeMove(move)
    nextMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
    score = -quiescienceSearch(gs, nextMoves, -beta, -alpha, -turnmultiplier)
    if score > maxScore:
        maxScore = score 
    gs.undoMove()
    if maxScore > alpha :
        alpha = maxScore
    if alpha >= beta :
        break

return maxScore
```

But this does not seem to work . The program takes a lot of time(It is considering a lot of options which are silly like queen taking some protected pawn and these options never seem to end.)The program just keeps on calculating and does not give any move even if DEPTH == 1.

How to rectify this ? I think I have made some mistake while implementing alpha-beta pruning in the quiescenceSearch function and how do I stop it from calculating silly moves like capturing a protected pawn ?

Comment: You link to a great source of code and then you use a completely different approach in your QS. How come? Just use the pseudo-code from chessprogramming, it works.

Comment: Thnx , it worked .

Comment: @Falcon what did you change to make it work?